# Highlight X number of cells based on numeric value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm creating a vacation tracker in excel. The first sheet pulls the data from SharePoint which has Start Date, End Date and a Date Difference calculation.

```
Sheet1
A2=12/16/2015
B2=12/20/2015
C2=5
```

The second sheet is the visualization of the data. It starts with cell `B1` and goes out for 90 days. It is a word representation of the date. Here is the formula I'm using `=UPPER(TEXT(B2,"DDD"))`

```
Sheet2
B1=WED
C1=THU
D1=FRI
E1=SAT
F1=SUN
```

The next row always `B2` has a formula which is always today's date. From there I add one date to increment the dates out to 90 days. `B2=Today()` and the other cells `=B2+1` and so forth

```
B2=16
C2=17
D2=18
E2=19
F2=20
```

What I'm trying to do is have the `start date` and `end date` highlighted on `Sheet2`. For example the boss is out on vacation from `12/16/2015` until `12/20/2015`. I need the cells `B3-F3` on `Sheet2` highlighted in Red. The secretary who is on leave from `12/17/2015` to `12/19/2015` have her cells highlighted in another color from cells `C4-E4.`

This will probably take some VBA I just need a starting point. I tried using a `VLOOKUP` to pull the data, however the using a range from another sheet is not working. And to be honest I do not know if this is the correct approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional formatting for `B2:ZZ2` at Sheet2

```
=AND(B2>=Sheet1!$A$2,B2<=Sheet1!$B$2)
```

And select the color you like

Comment: Thank you sir. This was exactly what I needed